# Unexpected token syntax error in a stateless function using arrow syntax

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, stateless, arrow-functions

Here is the error message:

```
SyntaxError: <local path>/Icon.jsx: Unexpected token (13:2)
  11 | 
  12 |   return (
> 13 |     <{props.component} onclick=props.onClick styleName=props.classNames style=props.style/>
     |      ^
  14 |   );
  15 | };
```

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this syntax error in the stateless function return, here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './Icon.css';

const Icon = (props) => {
  let classNames = `icon-${props.name}`;

  if (props.className) {
    classNames = `${classNames} ${props.className}`;
  }

  return (
    <{props.component} onclick={props.onClick} styleName={props.classNames} style={props.style} />
  );
};    

Icon.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  className: React.PropTypes.string,
  onClick: React.PropTypes.func,
  component: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([React.PropTypes.string, React.PropTypes.func]),
  style: React.PropTypes.object,
};

Icon.defaultProps = {
  component: 'span',
};

export default CSSModules(Icon, styles, { allowMultiple: true, errorWhenNotFound: false });
```

And here is the .babelrc config:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-runtime",
      "react-intl", {
        "messagesDir": "./build/messages",
        "enforceDescriptions": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And here is the very same component without a stateless function or arrow syntax which is working fine:

```
import React from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './Icon.css';

class Icon extends React.Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    Component: 'span',
  };

  /**
   * render component
   * @return {object}
   */
  render() {
    const {
      Component,
      name,
      className,
      style,
      onClick,
    } = this.props;
    let classNames = `icon-${name}`;

    if (className) {
      classNames = `${classNames} ${className}`;
    }
    return <Component onClick={onClick} styleName={classNames} style={style} />;
  }
}

Icon.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  className: React.PropTypes.string,
  onClick: React.PropTypes.func,
  Component: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([React.PropTypes.string, React.PropTypes.func]),
  style: React.PropTypes.object,
};


export default CSSModules(Icon, styles, { allowMultiple: true, errorWhenNotFound: false });
```

I've tried all the related answers without success, any suggestions?

Comment: syntax looks ok at first glance...have you checked to make sure that using `{props.component}` like this in JSX is valid? I don't know that it's not - just haven't seen it before. I will check in one of my apps.

Comment: I think so, I use it in other components that work fine, but somehow I'm making a mistake in this one.

Comment: what is props.component supposed to be? How i'm reading it is you are passing down a component into props and then binding all the other props into that component. But i could b reading it wrong

Comment: It represents the html tag or another component, in this case `span` by default, the naming is not good but I will fix it once I solve the problem

Comment: You cannot use `{...}` to compute the component name. See the spec: https://facebook.github.io/jsx/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to copy what you did before `const Component = props.component`

and then do `<Component onClick={props.onClick} styleName={props.classNames} style={props.style} />`

React distinguishes components from html by checking to see if the element is capitalized. In your case since you are just doing `<{props.component}' which react wont pick up as being a component and it wont know how to parse it as an html element either.

Comment: This solution worked fine. I think it would be even more useful if by any chance you know where this is documented and post the link, thanks anyways!

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components that goes over that part specifically

Comment: Adding to this answer, you could extract props to variables in function definition like so `const Icon = ({name, className, onClick, Component, style}) =>` Just remember to capitalize the `Component` in props though

Answer (score 0):

I think the `props.component` is causing this, not the arrow function syntax. This is what the error indicates as well.

For example in one of my apps, this works fine:

`return <About />`;

But this gives an identical error:

```
return <{'About'} />
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: /src/components/application.js: Unexpected token (89:16)

  88 |       case 'about':
> 89 |         return <{'About'} />;
     |                 ^
```

Unless there is a use scenario that I am missing, which is definitely possible. Easy to test though - what happens if you import a component you are expecting to render and use that in the JSX instead of `{props.component}`?

Comment: In your example `About` represents a string, in my example it represents a prop value, I've updated the question showing the same code without using a stateless function or arrow syntax and it works fine (that is, using braces).